Cant submit python automation to fill out form automaticaly
I have an automation to fill out a form automatically but when it tries to click the submit the form it doesn't work, even when I press manually, I don't know if the website has protections or if I am doing something wrong.
I tried to set up the automation to click the button and expected to go to another page
# Click the submit button
submit_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'wf-btn-submit')))
submit_button.click()

# Wait for the confirmation message
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='thank-you-confirmation']//h1[contains(text(), 'Thank you!')]")))

#Reload the form page for the next entry
driver.get('https://www.ibm.com/events/reg/flow/ibm/4n3tfimb/regcteba1/createaccount')`


are you getting an error message when running the code? what does "even when I press manually" mean--are you saying that the submit button doesn't work when you click it using your mouse?

no error message. When I press the button manually in the browser that the code open, it doesnt work aswell. In a normal browser it works fine.

ah ok, I understand. In that case, you're probably right that the page has protections against automation. Unfortunately there are a lot of different techniques used by websites to detect bots. You can try using some of the techniques discussed in this thread to get around it. You can also inspect the HTML for clues (if there is evidence of a bot manager, or if the button element is different on the page opened via Selenium) Maybe you can even just manually call the right JS function to submit the form; it really depends on the page
